# Keep sip registration in pjsua2 voip application even in deep sleep?

Tags: android, voip, pjsip

I have an android application with pjsua2 open source project.Its working fine both incoming and outgoing call.But when android goes in deep sleep sip registration not working.I am using service for registration.But its not reregistering..

```
 accCfg.getRegConfig().setRetryIntervalSec(600);
 accCfg.getRegConfig().setFirstRetryIntervalSec(15);
```

any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For when android goes in deep sleep android os kills almost all services and other background tasks. So for keeping sip registration I believe `AlarmManager` will be a very good option.Sample example will awake ur application in every 5 min..so re-register that time...

```
public void setAlarmManagerFroDeepSleep() {

    int interval = 1000 * 60 * 5;

    Intent alarmIntent = new Intent(this, AlarmReceiver.class);
    pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0, alarmIntent, 0);
    AlarmManager manager = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
    /* Repeating on every 5 minutes interval */
    manager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, interval,
            interval, pendingIntent);
}
```

Here is sample AlarmReciever class..

```
public class AlarmReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

    Log.e("Alerm Manager", "I'm running");

    if(Connectivity.isConnected(context)) {
        try {
            //make re-register here....
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
  }
}
```